'Publish web app' tab not loading. Visual Studio 2022
The publish tab gets stuck on an infinite load after right-clicking the project and selecting 'Publish Web App':
Screenshot
I have tried: updating, reinstalling, enterprise edition, community edition, deleting publish profiles, and repairing the install

Regarding your issue with the infinite loading of the publish tab, you can try the following methods:
1: You can run Visual Studio in safe mode using the command devenv /safemode and try again.
2: Check whether Live Share has been installed in the VS installer:

Here are some links to similar problems you can refer to: link1, link2.

Unfortunately didn't work

This is very strange, I wonder if you would accept the workaround mentioned in the second link and André Aranha in the comments, which is to create a PowerShell script to do the publishing.
